# What are some optimizations that I can make to a sorting algorithm if I only have to sort by 4 key values?

Tags: sorting, mergesort, gpu, binning

For more context, I implemented a Bitonic sorting network (type of parallel mergesort) for a GPU shader. The values that I am sorting are structured like so: 32 bit integers, the high 16 bits are 0, 1, 2, or 3 (that is to say, bits 18 to 31 are all zeroes), and the low 16 bits are values from 0 to 1023 inclusive. Everything starts out pre-sorted based on the lower bits. My primary goal is to sort everything based on the higher bits (putting everything into 4 bins, essentially). A secondary goal would be to have the lower bits in each bin in sorted order too, but that's not a huge priority. I'd happily sacrifice the sorted order of the lower bits if it means that my sort will complete more quickly.

Which leads into my issue; my bitonic sorting network shader completes more slowly than I'd like (takes about half a second). I suspect that it's all the memory barriers I'm putting up for the threadgroupshared memory. Would anyone have any suggestions for how to optimize the sorting algorithm for my particular situation?

I'm also open to reading alternative suggestions for how I might efficiently accomplish my primary goal (putting all my values of interest into their 4 bins within the context of a GPU shader).

Answer (score 0):

You could sort everything into 4 bins, but then you'd have to concatenate the bins. The alternative is a counting / radix sort where you make a single pass over the array to generate counts for upper bit values 0,1,2 (don't need a count for 3). These 3 counts would be the size of the first 3 "bins". The counts are then summed as shown below to generate an array index[] which contains the starting index for each of the 4 bins to be used for a radix sort:

```
value               starting index
upper bit value 0   0
upper bit value 1   (count of 0's)
upper bit value 2   (count of 0's)+(count of 1's)
upper bit value 3   (count of 0's)+(count of 1's)+(count of 2's)
```

The radix part inner loop would be something like:

```
output[index[upper bit value of input[i]]] = input[i]
index[upper bit value of input[i]] += 1
i += 1
```